# iOS Google Analytics SDK v3 and the IDFA

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, idfa

Many people have mentioned over the past year how incorporating Google Analytics for iOS apps without adverts leads to app rejection due to IDFA tracking being included. Version 3 of Analytics apparently doesn't enable IDFA tracking without including specific headers and setting the `allowIDFACollection` to `YES`.

I want to use Google Analytics only to track standard/anonymous events (button presses and screen views etc.) which doesn't require the IDFA tracker and I don't want to include adverts in my app but I keep seeing the following log when I run the app:

```
idfa class missing, won't collect idfa
```

Do I have to somehow disable this log entry for the app to be approved, or would this log entry result in the app being rejected?

Also when the app is being submitted to the App Store there is an iTunes Connect question asking whether the app uses the IDFA tracker. I would assume this would be set to NO, but because the Google Analytics library provides the ability to use the IDFA tracker, do I have to select YES?